# Python pandas - remove groups based on NaN count threshold

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset based on different weather stations,

```
stationID | Time | Temperature | ...
----------+------+-------------+-------
123       |  1   |     30      |
123       |  2   |     31      |
202       |  1   |     24      |
202       |  2   |     24.3    |
202       |  3   |     NaN     |
...
```

And I would like to remove 'stationID' groups, which have more than a certain number of NaNs. For instance, if I type:

```
**>>> df.groupby('stationID')**
```

then, I would like to drop groups that have (at least) a certain number of NaNs (say 30) within a group. As I understand it, I cannot use dropna(thresh=10) with groupby:

```
**>>> df2.groupby('station').dropna(thresh=30)**
*AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'dropna' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects...*
```

So, what would be the best way to do that with Pandas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IIUC you can do  `df2.loc[df2.groupby('station')['Temperature'].filter(lambda x: len(x[pd.isnull(x)] ) < 30).index]`

Example:

```
In [59]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2], 'val':[1,1,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan, 1,1,1,1]})
df

Out[59]:
   id  val
0   0  1.0
1   0  1.0
2   0  NaN
3   1  1.0
4   1  NaN
5   1  NaN
6   2  1.0
7   2  1.0
8   2  1.0
9   2  1.0

In [64]:    
df.loc[df.groupby('id')['val'].filter(lambda x: len(x[pd.isnull(x)] ) < 2).index]

Out[64]:
   id  val
0   0  1.0
1   0  1.0
2   0  NaN
6   2  1.0
7   2  1.0
8   2  1.0
9   2  1.0
```

So this will filter out the groups that have more than 1 nan values

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I have other variables other than temperature. So, using your code, how would I take into account the collective sum of NaNs (i.e.: I would like to remove a group, where the collective sum of NaNs in variable1, variable2, variable3,... is less than a threshold)

Comment: @mmeclimate, its not fair/right to change the question after its been answered. You should ask another question and give the added details.

Comment: Got it. I'll do that.

Comment: Using the method from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38574872/python-pandas-remove-group-based-on-collective-nan-count), I found that for a ~1M length series `len(x[pd.isnull(x)])` took 2x the time vs. `x.isnull().sum()` (3sec vs. 1.6sec for 1000 loops). I also think the latter looks cleaner/more concise.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a column to give the the number of null values by station_id, and then use `loc` to select the relevant data for further processing.

```
df['station_id_null_count'] = \
    df.groupby('stationID').Temperature.transform(lambda group: group.isnull().sum())
df.loc[df.station_id_null_count > 30, :]  # Select relevant data
```

Answer (score 0):

Using @EdChum setup:  Since you dont mention your final output, adding this.

```
   vals = df.groupby(['id'])['val'].apply(lambda x: (np.size(x)-x.count()) < 2 ) 

   vals[vals]

   id
   0    True
   2    True
   Name: val, dtype: bool
```