# Python pandas - remove group based on collective NaN count

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset based on different weather stations for several variables (Temperature, Pressure, etc.),

```
stationID | Time | Temperature | Pressure |...
----------+------+-------------+----------+
123       |  1   |     30      |  1010.5  |
123       |  2   |     31      |  1009.0  |
202       |  1   |     24      |  NaN     |
202       |  2   |     24.3    |  NaN     |
202       |  3   |     NaN     |  1000.3  |
...
```

And I would like to remove 'stationID' groups, which have more than a certain number of NaNs (taking into account all variables in the count).

If I try,

```
df.loc[df.groupby('station')['temperature'].filter(lambda x: len(x[pd.isnull(x)] ) < 30).index]
```

it works, as shown here: [Python pandas - remove groups based on NaN count threshold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38572079/python-pandas-remove-groups-based-on-nan-count-threshold)

But the above example takes into account 'temperature' only. So, **how can I take into account the collective sum of NaNs of the available variables?** i.e.: I would like to remove a group, where the collective sum of NaNs in [variable1, variable2, variable3,...] is less than a threshold.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work:

```
df.groupby('stationID').filter(lambda g: g.isnull().sum().sum() < 4)
```

You can replace `4` with a threshold number you would like it to be.

```
df.groupby('stationID').filter(lambda g: g.isnull().sum().sum() < 4)

   stationID    Time    Temperature Pressure
0        123       1           30.0   1010.5
1        123       2           31.0   1009.0
2        202       1           24.0      NaN
3        202       2           24.3      NaN
4        202       3            NaN   1000.3


df.groupby('stationID').filter(lambda g: g.isnull().sum().sum() < 3)

   stationID    Time    Temperature Pressure
0        123       1           30.0   1010.5
1        123       2           31.0   1009.0
```

Comment: @MaxU Thanks. It doesn't seem like we have a function to sum across the data frame.

Comment: `df.groupby('stationID').filter(lambda g: g.isnull().values.sum() < 3)` -- on values you could do `sum` once.