# How can I drop all rows in a group if any column contains only nan values for that group?

Tags: pandas, group-by

I am trying to drop all rows that belong to a group if within that group there exists a column that only contains nan values.

For example:

| ID | Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | Nan |
| 1 | 3 | Nan |
| 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 | Nan |
| 3 | NaN | 4 |
| 4 | Nan | Nan |
| 4 | NaN | 4 |

In this case, I want only the rows for ID 1 and ID 4 to be removed, as Column B contains only nans for ID 1 and Column A contains only nans for ID 4. Group 2 is fine because no nans, group 3 is fine because neither column contains only nan.

In other words, my expected output is this:

| ID | Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 | Nan |
| 3 | NaN | 4 |

How do I achieve this?

I tried following [Python pandas - remove group based on collective NaN count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38574872/python-pandas-remove-group-based-on-collective-nan-count), but this only takes into account either a single column, or aggregates nans across all columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter out by condition:

```
df.groupby('ID').filter(lambda x: ~(x.isna().all().any()))
```

---

```
   ID Column A Column B
2   2       2         3
3   3       3      None
4   3     None        4
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much, the all().any() was the key that I didn't get figured out for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
grouped = df.groupby('ID').sum()
grouped = grouped[grouped['Column B'] > 0]
df[df.index.isin(grouped.index)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need it to check for all columns, so column A as well. Maybe I wasn't clear enough about that, I will make that more clear it in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
df.groupby('ID').filter(lambda x: x['Column B'].notna().sum() > 0)
```

output:

```
    ID  Column A    Column B
2   2   2.0         3
3   3   3.0         NaN
4   3   NaN         4
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need it to check for all columns, so column A as well. Maybe I wasn't clear enough about that, I will make that more clear it in my original question.